Import file in MATLAB into the script
I have a script config.m and it contains e.g.
par.path = 'path for processing';
par.anotherpath = par.scan_path;
par.configing = 2;

I would like to use this as if I stated it in execute.m script
load config.m
%program logic

I have not found a way how to include one file to another so that the variables will be visible.

Just config will run the script.

...or config() if you want to make it obvious you're calling something, or run('some/folder/path/config.m') if the config file isn't on your path.
